# Large range duplicate removal from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The object is to remove all the rows in sheet1 column A if they exist in the list in sheet2 column A.
Both columns only contain numbers.
Sheet one column A may contain duplicates which is fine if they are not on the list in sheet2.

One option that I'm not familiar with and might be missing out on is Autofilter.

The code executes on a small data range 100 to 1000 but I have many books with over 1,000,000 records to clean up and anything over 10,000 brings Excel to not responding and freezes up indefinitely.

```vb
Sub remDupesfromTwoWs()

With Application 
    .EnableEvents = False 
    CalcMode = .Calculation 
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
    .ScreenUpdating = False 
End With 
 
 ' set range to be searched
 
Dim masterRecordRange As Range ' declare an unallocated array.
Set masterRecordRange = Range("Sheet1!A2:A316730") ' masterRecordRange is now an allocated array
 
 ' store sheet2 column A as searchfor array
 
Dim unwantedRecords() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
unwantedRecords = Range("Sheet2!A1:A282393") ' unwantedRecords is now an allocated array
 
 ' foreach masterRecord loop to search masterRecordRange for match in unwantedRecords
Dim i As Double 
Dim delRange As Range 
Set delRange = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count) 
 
 'go through all rows starting at last row
For i = masterRecordRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 
     
     ' loop through unwantedRecords check each offset
    For Each findMe In unwantedRecords 
         
         'If StrComp(cell, findMe, 1) = 0 Then not as fast
         
         ' unwantedRecord found
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = findMe Then 
             
            Set delRange = Union(delRange, Range("A" & i)) 
             
             'MsgBox i
             
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next findMe 
Next i 
 
 'remove them all in one shot
delRange.EntireRow.Delete 
With Application 
    .EnableEvents = True 
    CalcMode = .Calculation 
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
    .ScreenUpdating = True 
End With 
 'possibly count and display quantity found
MsgBox "finally done!" 
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very slow to walk through a range one cell at a time because there is a large overhead on each call to Cells. So you should get both ranges into variant arrays, then compare them to build up another array of matches which you would then write back to the worksheet and use Autofilter to select the rows to delete.
Here is a blog post on various methods of comparing lists:
[VBA Comparing lists shootout](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/)

The fastest method is to use either a Dictionary or a collection. You should be able to adapt the code to do what you want.

Comment: Charles Williams, Autofilter is my friend! I was able to pull 357,000 records from 591,000 in 11 minutes thanks for the direction!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried Range.Find:

```
Sub TestIt()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long, CurRow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DestLast = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = LastRow to 2 Step -1 'Must go backwards because you are deleting rows
    If Not ws2.Range("A2:A" & DestLast).Find(ws1.Range("A" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) is Nothing Then
        Range("A" & CurRow).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Chrismas007, That was my first attempt actually and it works on smaller datasets wonderfully, just gets insanely slow with hundreds of thousands of records, thanks for looking!!